# how to convert properties file to JSON using scala

Tags: scala

How to convert properties file to JSON using scala

Properties file contains

```
a.b.10=C 
a.b.11=C50
a.b.12=C508
```

Output should be
`{"a":{"b":{"10":"C","11":"C50","12":"C508"}}}`

Comment: Have no clue how to achieve it.

Comment: writing a simple parser combinator is your go to choice for stuff like this. I recommend reading through chapter 9 of the book: [Functional programming in scala book](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13541678-functional-programming-in-scala)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`circe-config`](https://github.com/circe/circe-config). Example:

```
import io.circe.config.parser.parse

val result = parse("""
  a.b.10=C 
  a.b.11=C50
  a.b.12=C508
""").map(_.noSpaces)
```

The example above will produce an `Either[ParsingFailure, String]`, which you can then destructure to handle failures, for example

```
result match {
  case Left(failure) => // handle parsing failure
  case Right(jsonString) => // do something with your json string
}
```

The json string produced by the example above is:

```
{"a":{"b":{"12":"C508","10":"C","11":"C50"}}}
```

Comment: After googling i found to add the dependency library in sbt, i have added the dependency library while building the sbt i am facing error " not found: value circeVersion
).map(_ % circeVersion)" could you please help any way forward.

Comment: You literally just need `"io.circe" %% "circe-config" % "0.4.1"` from the circe-config readme. Also, I suggest some guide on sbt, since you seem to miss some basic concepts of libray dependencies. Here's a good start https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Dependencies.html